# Determining whether a condition holds for all members of a list

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

This is something that has eluded me for a while. For example, say I had a list of numbers, and I wanted to check if each number was divisible by EVERY number in another list, how would I do that? All I can think of is:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,etc...]
divisible = [1,2,3,4,5,6,etc...]
for i in mylist:
    for x in divisible:
        if i % x == 0:
            <do something>
```

Obviously, this will only check if any element in `mylist` is divisible by any element in 'divisible', but not if it's divisible by ALL the elements in that list. How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `all`:

```
>>> i = 2*3*17*23
>>> divs = [2, 17, 23]
>>> all(i % x == 0 for x in divs)
True
>>> all(i % x == 0 for x in [2,13,17])
False
```

See also `any` and `next`:

```
>>> any(i % x == 0 for x in [5, 17, 101])
True
>>> next(x for x in [5, 17, 101] if i % x == 0)
17
```

Comment: With my FP hat on, I should be embarrassed for having come up with an procedural solution; this is far cleaner.

Comment: In relation to this, how would I get it to return the numbers from 'i' which is divisible by every number in 'divs', rather than just true?

Comment: @user2253076: usually when you have a separate question it's better to ask that separately.  But a listcomp like `[i for i in mylist if all(i % x == 0 for x in divs)]` should do it.